# wcf service can't update a dbf file - "read only" error

Tags: wcf, visual-foxpro

I have a wcf 4 service that is trying to add a record to a visual fox pro dbf file on the same server.  When it tries to do the insert I get "Cannot update the cursor USER, since it is read-only."

I assume that this is a permissions problem.  What do I have to do to give permission to the wcf service to update my dbf file?

This works on my develpment machine.

Here is some of the code:

```
 OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection("provider=vfpoledb;Data Source="\\data\\tt.dbc");
            oConn.Open();
 OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                     oCommand.Connection = oConn;
                     oCommand.CommandText = "SET NULL OFF\r\nSET DELETED ON";
                     oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into user (lastname,firstname) values ('Doe','John')", oConn);
            mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                         lnRet = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a permissions problem - that would generate an access denied error.

Two things to check:

1. Is the file marked as read-only?
2. Is the file being used by any other process?

I think #2 is more likely - I haven't done FoxPro, but I've done a lot of dBase with Clipper, and at least under dBase the file has to be opened exclusively (i.e., not shared) to do inserts/updates/deletions.

Comment: I have a lot of experience with dbfs - and never had a need to open a file exclusively to update it.  Maybe there is a problem using vfpoledb?

Comment: And as I mentioned, in a similar scenario on my development machine it works fine.

Comment: It might be with vfpoledb - I haven't used that particular driver.  I haven't yet had to update a DBF through any sort of OleDb, so maybe having it exclusive isn't an issue with OleDb; it is going through Clipper.

Comment: Like I said, the same configuration works on my development machine - it must be a permissions issue.

Comment: Visual FoxPro tables absolutely don't have to be open exclusively for CRUD operations. Only PACK and ZAP operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that the credentials that are used to run the WCF service have Read/Write access to the data UNC path.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I determine which credentials are used to run the WCF service?

Comment: If your WCF Service is hosted in IIS, you can check for the Application Pool credentials.  Otherwise, you can see the credentials by finding the process in the task manager.